# How to register mysql db from my web host in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin, japplet

I have built a desktop application and I used jdbc (localhost) in order to test it. Now I want to built a applet, that's why I need to get connection to mysql database which I created on my web host by using phpMyAdmin in NetBeans.  I have found a way actually, I click `"Services"` and rightclick `"Database"` then click `"Register Mysql Server.."`. I know db username and password but I don't know what to write in `"Server Host Name"` and `"Port"`. So if it can be done in this way how I find `"Server Host Name"` and `"Port"` if not how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

ServerHostName could be a name or also an IP address. Port for mysql is normally 3306. Maybe this information is enough, but sometimes webHost manager can change this access for security reasons, in this case you must contact your provider

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The host is the server host name.